# \input ignores table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, input

I have divided my tex files as follows:

```
.
├── content
│   ├── abstract.tex
│   ├── mainA
│   │   └── a.tex
│   ├── mainB.tex
│   ├── mainC.tex
│   └── MainD
│       ├── d.tex
│       └── dd.tex
├── main.tex
```

In my main.tex file, I `include` all these files.

My 
`\tableofcontents` just outputs one line with title. What am I missing? Below is my MWP.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\begin{document}
\title{How fancy can the title be}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{content/mainA/a.tex}
\input{content/mainB.tex}
\input{content/mainC.tex}
\input{content/mainD/d.tex}
\input{content/mainD/dd.tex}


\bibliography{references}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to have main.tex compiled several times without having auxiliary files (.aux, .toc, etc) deleted between the single compilation-runs.

Comment: did you compile twice?

Comment: I did. It didn't do anything better

Comment: Then deliver a minimal (non-)working example which the reader can copy and compile as is for reproducing the erroneous behavior. By the way: In the subject-line you write `\input`, in text of the question you write `include`. Do you use plain TeX? Do you use LaTeX? If LaTeX: Is there some `\includeonly`-directive which prevents other files than the one containing the `\tableofcontents`-command from being processed/included? If so, these other files will not contribute to the table of contents, and from time to time you need to compile without the `\includeonly`-directive...

Comment: the file structure and `\input` are unrelated to `\tableofcontents` so if you have an error in the table of contents you need to show some example code.

Comment: What are `content` and `MainA` and `MainD`? Are these just some directories on the storage device where you maintain your .tex-input-files?  The tree shown in your question: Is that just the directory-tree where you can see under what directory-paths some of your .tex-input-files are stored?  Or does that tree mirror the course of reading the single .tex-input-files? Did you make sure that (La)TeX does indeed "look" for .tex-input-files within those directories which you wish it to?

Comment: Yes, the tree is the directory tree and you are right content is a folder (same level as main.text), which contains mainA and mainD as subfolders.

Comment: surprisingly, when I was trying to create the MWE for you folks, the MWE is working, but the actual folder still has same issue.

Comment: Is ensured that (La)TeX does search for .tex-input-files in these sub-folders when encountering corresponding `\input/\include`-commands? (Be aware that beneath other things, on some TeX-platforms some of the folders searched for .tex-input-files depend on the account under which one is logged into the machine...)

Comment: Oh, how to ensure them?

Comment: E.g., if `main.tex` is in folder `foo` you may need to write `\input{foo/content/MainD/d.tex}` or `\input{"foo/content/MainD/d.tex"}` or `\input{./content/MainD/d.tex}` or `\input{"./content/MainD/d.tex"}` or the like for enabling LaTeX to find the file `d.tex` as if you just write `\input{d.tex}`, LaTeX will search for file `foo/d.tex` which does not exist... (Here I used the LaTeX-syntax for `\input`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95492/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-ulrich-diez).